# Facebook like count is increasing with facebook share in laravel

Tags: php, facebook, laravel-5.4, facebook-like, facebook-sharer

I am using `laravel 5.4` . So in my projects there is `Facebook` share and like button. The problem is when I share the content the like count is also getting increased. Why is this happening and how to solve this?

Here is the `js-sdk` included in the layout right after body tag

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId            : '{{ env('FACEBOOK_APP_ID') }}',
            autoLogAppEvents : true,
            xfbml            : true,
            version          : 'v2.12'
        });
    };

    (function(d, s, id){
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

here is the code for share button

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://pustokbd.com/blogs/{{$Blog->parma_link}}" data-layout="button_count" data-size="large" data-mobile-iframe="true">Share</div>
```

And the code for like button

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://pustokbd.com/blogs/{{$Blog->parma_link}}" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-size="large" data-share="false"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is when I share the content the like count is also getting increased. Why is this happening

Because there is *only one* counter.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/faqs#faq_233117017073109:

> What makes up the number shown next to my Like button?
>
> The number shown is the sum of:
>
> - The number of likes of your URL
> - The number of shares of your URL (this includes copy/pasting a link back to Facebook)
> - The number of likes and comments on stories on Facebook about your URL

.

> and how to solve this?

Nothing to solve, works as designed.